# whats the diffrence between calling a route by type the path in adress bar.. and calling it by clicking an <a> element

Tags: laravel, url, view, path, routes

im talking about laravel. the problem is when i click the  element to delete a worker. that works great but when i type the same href path in adress bar it says page not found 403 forbiden.
so why it works with event click but not when you type it manually in adress bar

thats my script

**the php blade file** :

```
    @foreach ($collection as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->email}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{route("delete-worker")}}/{{$item->id}}">delete</a> </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**the route file web.php** :

```
Route::get('/delete-worker/{id?}', [workersController::class, 'deleteWorker'])->name("delete-worker");
```

**the controller file** :

```
function deleteworker($id){
   DB::table('workers')->delete($id);
   return back()->with("delete-success","worker with id $id have been deleted from database");
}
```

Comment: The method is get, so both are same.

Comment: change it as `<a href="{{route("delete-worker",$item->id)}}">delete</a>`

Comment: Maybe because of caching? Did you try to reload without cache? Usually works with ctrl+shift+R.

Answer (score 0):

You need use form for deleting and change your route method to DELETE.

```
   Route::delete('/delete-worker/{id?}', [workersController::class, 'deleteWorker'])->name("delete-worker");

    


  @foreach ($collection as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->email}}</td>
            <td>
             <form method="POST" action="{{route("delete-worker", $item->id)}}">
                 @csrf
                 @method('DELETE')
                 <button type="submit">delete</button> 
             </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
    @endforeach
```